# Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined in env file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const { mongoose } = require('mongoose');

// const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const DB = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_DB_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.70g8h.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB_DATABASE}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
mongoose.connect( DB ,
 {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true
  })
.then( ()=>console.log('Connection Success ..'))
.catch( (err)=>console.log(' Not Connection Success'));

dotenv.config({path:'./config.env'});
app.get('/', (req, res,next) => {
    
    res.status(200).json({
        message:'Hello'
    });

});
app.post('/data', (req, res,next) => {
    
    res.status(200).json({
        message: req.body
    });
    

});



app.listen(process.env.PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`Server is runing at the port : ${process.env.PORT}`);
})
```

Getting this error when using this code, I would like to know what is causing the error and any possible fixes. I am using atlas MongoDB

```
this is the output 

D:\WebDevelopment.Ravi\Projects\mern_ecommerce\e-commerce-backend\src\index.server.js:9
mongoose.connect( DB ,
         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\WebDevelopment.Ravi\Projects\mern_ecommerce\e-commerce-backend\src\index.server.js:9:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..
```

Getting this error when using this code, I would like to know what is causing the error and any possible fixes. I am using atlas MongoDB

Answer (score 1):

From ths docs [Getting Started](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html). It should be `const mongoose = require('mongoose');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work:

```
const mongoose =require("mongoose");
require('dotenv').config();
```